# Use generic type class without specifying the type in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have (in a provider class using Entity Framework) two derived classes from a generic "MyContext" like this:

```
public abstract partial class MyContext<T> : DbContext where T : DbContext
{
  protected MyContext(DbContextOptions<T> options) : base(options) { }
  
// Here goes the rest of my code for MyContext 
}

public class MyPrimaryContext : MyContext<MyPrimaryContext>
{
    public MyPrimaryContext(DbContextOptions<MyPrimaryContext> options) : base(options) { }
}

public class MySecondaryContext : MyContext<MySecondaryContext>
{
    public MySecondaryContext(DbContextOptions<MySecondaryContext> options) : base(options) { }
}
```

Now, in my consuming provider class, I want to use either of the derived classes depending on which DbContext I like to use. So I would like to do something like:

```
MyPrimaryContext originalContext; // Not showing the initialization here..
MySecondaryContext backupContext; // Not showing the initialization here.. 

MyContext resolvedContextToUse;

if (<some condition>)
{
    resolvedContextToUse = backupContext;
}
else
{
    resolvedContextToUse = originalContext;
}
```

But I get "Using the generic type 'MyContext' requires 1 type arguments".
Is there any way to define a variable of the generic base class without specifying the type, and let the runtime resolve the type in the assignments? Like we do for ordinary inheritance?
Or is the concept base class and inheritance not applicable here?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

Of course @shingo is right: you already have a common base class here

## edit2:

he modified/deleted his original comment:
He stated that `DbContext` is the common base class here, so that can be used.

But in all *other* situations: The "usual" way to go would be to define a common, non-generic base class (or interface)

E.g.

```cs
public MyClass {}

public class MyClass<T> : MyClass
{
[...]
```

However, all method's inside this non-generic interface/class of course cannot use `T`. That could matter for return types, for instance.

This is already done all over the core library. For instance, all `Task<T>` derive from `Task`. (which for instance makes it a lot easier to await different derived types together)